# IMvxResourceLoader: How to use it (MvvmCross v2)

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

What are the steps that need to be followed to use IMvxResourceloader (MvvmCross v2) in our project. I tried as follows

```
public class AboutViewModel : BaseViewModel, IMvxServiceConsumer
{

    private const string FileName = "Html/AboutApp.html";
    public AboutViewModel()
    {
        var resourceLoader = this.GetService<IMvxResourceLoader>();
        string HelpText = resourceLoader.GetTextResource(FileName);
    }

}
```

but failed.

If I remove the lines inside AboutViewModel(), app is working fine.

If I use these lines, I am not able to display About View Model.

Any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

In addition to this

I am trying to initialise "resourceloader" plugin as

```
   private void InitialisePlugins()
    {
        Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Location.PluginLoader.Instance.EnsureLoaded();
        Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.PhoneCall.PluginLoader.Instance.EnsureLoaded();
        Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.SMS.PluginLoader.Instance.EnsureLoaded();
        Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Email.PluginLoader.Instance.EnsureLoaded();
        Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.ResourceLoader.PluginLoader.Instance.EnsureLoaded ();
    }
```

following error is comming up. I am using MvvmCross V2.

Cirrious.MvvmCross.Exceptions.MvxException: plugin not registered for type Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.ResourceLoader
  at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Platform.MvxLoaderBasedPluginManager.LoadPlugin (System.Type toLoad) [0x0003a] in /Users/macbook2/EmployeeOffers_Aug_05/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross/Plugins/MvxLoaderBasedPluginManager.cs:38
  at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.MvxBasePluginManager.ExceptionWrappedLoadPlugin (System.Type toLoad) [0x00000] in /Users/macbook2/EmployeeAVC_Aug_05/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross/Plugins/MvxBasePluginManager.cs:49

Comment: what does 'failed' mean? An exception - in which case can you provide the trace and the exception details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`plugin not registered` is quite a clear error message - it suggests that the plugin isn't registered...

What's missing I guess is the information about which plugin is not registered - can you get the debugger to tell you that - e.g. by asking the debugger to stop when `MvxException`s are thrown.

My guess is that it will either be the `File` or the `ResourceLoader` plugin (because resources relied on files in vNext/v2).

Whichever it is, make sure you have the platform-specific plugin referenced - exactly as you do for `PhoneCall`, `Location`, etc

---

Aside> in v3 this error would probably surface in a different way - basically with a service not found error when trying to resolve the file store at runtime.